# F# HtmlProvider to HtmlNode

Tags: f#

I can find specific row with `HtmlProvider`.

Is it possible to get another html information from `HtmlProvider.Tables.Row`?

```
type Provider = HtmlProvider<"
<table><tbody>
 <tr><td class=\"orange\" >something2</td><td>20.1</td></tr>
 <tr><td class=\"grean\" >something</td><td>23.5</td></tr>
 <tr><td class=\"orange\" >something3</td><td>20.0</td></tr>
</tbody></table>">// backslashes are for escaping

let wantedRow = Provider.GetSample().Tables.Table1.Rows 
                |> Seq.filter (fun c->if float (c.Column2)=20.0 then true else false)
                |> Seq.head
```

Now I have `wantedRow` and can extract `something3` string.

But I need to get `class` of that row (`orange`).

Something like this written in **pseudocode** (`GetHtml` is pseudo..):

```
(*Pseudo code warning *)
let tdTag= wantedRow.GetHtml.Descendants["td"] |>Seq.head 
let classStr = tdOfWantedRow.AttributeValue ("class")  //orange
```

Is it possible to get such information with ease of `HtmlProvider`?

Comment: Side-note: you can use `"""` as a string delimiter and you won't have to escape anything inside.

Comment: @Tarmil Great !

Answer (score 3):

The `Tables` functionality of the `HtmlProvider` treats the table as data, discarding html attributes. To get at the HTML itself, you can resort to treating it like an HTML document:

```fs
let wantedRow = Provider.GetSample().Html.Descendants("tr")
                |> Seq.filter (fun x -> float((x.Descendants("td") |> Seq.item 1).InnerText()) = float(20.0))
                |> Seq.head

let cssClass = (wantedRow.Descendants() |> Seq.head).Attribute("class").Value()

printf "%s\n" cssClass
// prints "orange"
```

(of course, in a real world example, you'll want some safeguards in case nodes don't exist or the floats don't parse, but this should get you headed in the right direction)